# HTML/CSS: IMG with height equal to the height of document (not the window)

Tags: html, css, window, height, document

How can I achieve that  effect?

Answer (score 2):

For full horizontal and vertical try something like:

```
background-image: url(image.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
background-attachment:fixed;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
```

or better post a your code in a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Make that position absolute. ;)

Comment: @Alerty If that works for you, good. But where I work, I can't always rely on CSS properties that aren't implemented in IE6/7/8, especially when the difference is a stretched image to one single image centred.

Comment: @alex: You should rejoice that IE9 is coming someday. People on IE are missing out a lot!

Comment: @Alerty They sure are, but unfortunately, the majority of people have barriers in place that prevent them from upgrading, such as business costs and lack of knowledge of alternatives.

Comment: @alex: Like the government of UK which is stuck on IE6. :P

Answer (score 1):

Your problem most likely stems from the fact that the body tag is positioned statically, so heights of its children are relative to the html tag.

Try adding this:

```
body{
  position:relative;
}
```

It will make the body's children use the document's size rather than the browser viewport.

Here is an example of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/cP9hu/

Comment: Wouldn't it be more likely the text should be over the image? Also, I did downvote you, because I believe calling other people's solutions (even if incorrect) crazy is rude. Stack Overflow encourages people to act friendly to others.

Comment: Ahaha, the text is just to expand the content, if you want it to be over the image, then put it over the image, it's not hard. (wrap it in a div, and position it.) And the hypocrisy of your statement is cute.

Comment: @david For the sake of it, can you demonstrate the text over the image?

Comment: sure, http://jsfiddle.net/cP9hu/1/ is using positioning on the text block, alternatively you can set a negative z-index on the image, to put it where the background of the parent would be, like here http://jsfiddle.net/cP9hu/2/ but I prefer to avoid z-indices for things like that.

Comment: @david Do you avoid playing with `z-index` because of IE7's muddling of them?

Comment: It's more because of how often z-index is used in horrible hacks rather than in places where it should be used. If, conceptually, the idea behind this image was to have it as a background of the parent, then I'd be okay with using a negative z-index, but otherwise that could cause issues later on.
You will often see places where people have put z-index:9999; because they don't understand the concept of stacking contexts: http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex

Answer (score 0):

If there's a reason that this doesn't work:

CSS Code

```
    #theImage {
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Then with jQuery you could do this:

```
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    $('#theImage').css('height', docHeight);
```

I'm not sure how to do this in plain old JavaScript, but that's the jQuery example.

Comment: "It is tempting, if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it were a nail." Don't use jquery for something as simple as this.

Answer (score -1):

That sounds like something that might have to be handled via JavaScript. Personally I would use jQuery and something to the effect of:

```
$(document).ready(function() { //Runs at page load
    $(".ID_OF_IMAGE").each(function() { //calls the anon function for the id tag specified
        /*sets the height to the max of three methods of height measurement
        diff browsers detect doc height differently.*/
        this.height = Math.max(
            //gets the larger between doc height and body height
            Math.max(document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight),
            Math.max(document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight),
            Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight))
    });
});
```

Alternately you can set the image as a background of a div or the body and use the repeat-y css property.

```
body { //also works for div's
    background-image:url('image.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

-SB

Comment: "It is tempting, if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it were a nail." Don't use jquery for something as simple as this.

Comment: Never ever over use JavaScript. ;)